# How to exclude a specific subdomain from wildcard domain (Nginx)

Tags: nginx, wildcard-subdomain

For example, I have a domain **example.com**, the web app will create subdomain when user sign up.

- **foo.example.com** will point to the same site
- **bar.example.com** will point to the same site

But I want to create a testing environment, e.g. **demo.example.com** which will point to another project. When user sign up, it will have

- **foo.demo.example.com**
- **bar.demo.example.com**

Currently what I have

```
| Name           | Type  | Value           |
|----------------|-------|-----------------|
| example.com.   | A     | 123.123.123.123 |
| *.example.com. | CNAME | example.com.    |
```

And my nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/example.com/public;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;

    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

How can I create 1 for testing environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create a new server block with subdomain fqdn as server_name and nginx will follow this order of precedence.

1. Exact name
2. Longest wildcard name starting with an asterisk, e.g. “*.example.org”
3. Longest wildcard name ending with an asterisk, e.g. “mail.*”
4. First matching regular expression (in order of appearance in a configuration file)

For more info.: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html